# MustInherit with own type as as parameter

Tags: vb.net

I have two libraries in a 3-tier project - call them BO and DAL. Almost every class in DAL implements a Save Method:

```
Public Function Save(ByVal someObject As BO.SomeType) As Boolean
```

As I have to add the missing Save methods, I though it was a good idea to create an interface which implements a 'MustInherit Save' function. So if I type:

```
MustOverride Function Save(ByVal someObject As BO.SomeType) As Boolean
```

That should do the trick; but the type of the parameter is always different. For example, in class DAL.TypeA:

```
Public Function Save(ByVal someObject As BO.SomeTypeA) As Boolean
```

And in class DAL.TypeB:

```
Public Function Save(ByVal someObject As BO.SomeTypeB) As Boolean
```

Is there a way to handle different type of parameters in an interface? Some kind of generic? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perfect use case for [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Using a generic interface:

**Interface:**

```
Interface ISave(Of T)

    Function Save(someObject As T) As Boolean

End Interface
```

---

**Implementation:**

```
Class BoClass
    Implements ISave(Of BoClass)

    Public Function Save(someObject As BoClass) As Boolean Implements ISave(Of BoClass).Save
    End Function

End Class

Class DalClass
    Implements ISave(Of DalClass)

    Public Function Save(someObject As DalClass) As Boolean Implements ISave(Of DalClass).Save
    End Function

End Class
```

---

Or, using a generic base class instead of an interface

**Base class**

```
MustInherit Class BaseClass(Of T)

    MustOverride Function Save(someObject As T) As Boolean

End Class
```

---

**Implementation**

```
Class BoClass
    Inherits BaseClass(Of BoClass)

    Public Overrides Function Save(someObject As BoClass) As Boolean
    End Function

End Class

Class DalClass
    Inherits BaseClass(Of DalClass)

    Public Overrides Function Save(someObject As DalClass) As Boolean
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks so much for your fast answer and the examples. I was aware of the generics, but I didn't know the `Class BaseClass(Of T)` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an implementation detail, in which case, the objects you are saving should implement an interface that your DAL class would call.

```
Public Interface ISaveable
  Function Save() As Boolean
End Interface
```

Then the objects that do the actual saving implement it:

```
Public Class BOItem
  Implements ISaveable

  Public Function Save() As Boolean Implements ISaveable.Save
    'do the actual saving here
  End Function
End Class
```

Your base class would then just ask for the interface:

```
Public MustInherit Class DAL
  MustOverride Function Save(someObject As ISaveable) As Boolean
End Class
```

And then when you create DAL objects, you won't have to worry about what type of object it is, you just call save:

```
Public Class DALItem
  Inherits DAL

  Public Overrides Function Save(someObject As ISaveable) As Boolean
    Return someObject.Save()
  End Function
End Class
```

Comment: I thought about that, but my BO (actually Business Object) library shouldn't access the database... the main problem in my project is DAL referencing BO instead of BO referencing DAL - in that case the problem would not arise. I've planned to change this, but later... anyway, thanks for the answer :)